# Get root domain from location.host

Tags: javascript, string-parsing

There are a lot of SO questions that seem to address variations of this question. But they tend to be complex regex answers and I am hoping I can find something simpler.

Given location.host values of

```
foo.mysite.com
app.foo.mysite.com
mysite.com
```

How can I get the root domain `mysite.com`?

I could do something like finding the second to last `.`, but this seems ugly and wouldn't work for any TLD's like `.co.uk`. If jQuery has an object that contains this information I am happy to use it.

My goal is to create cookies that exist across all subdomains. To do this I need to find `.mysite.com`. I'd prefer not to hardcode it.

Comment: Given a list of valid TLDs it shouldn't be hard - instead of the second to last `.` you want the first `.` (reading right-to-left) after the TLD. You could do this with a big regexp or a loop, but the latter would typically be less efficient.

Comment: A complete list can be found here: http://publicsuffix.org/ Whether you use a regex or some other way won't make much of a difference I guess. In any case you have to consider all the public TLDs and SLDs. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452916/need-a-regular-expression-to-capture-second-level-domain-sld.

Comment: There's a project to do this at https://github.com/riffraff/publicsuffix.js but it claims to be "broken." I haven't tried it but it could form the basis for your solution.

Comment: @FelixKling - thanks, that's perfect. Voting to close my own question.

Comment: If it really helped you, you can also just delete your question... just saying :) Happy coding!

Comment: There are countries with optional 2nd level domains (i.e. both some-domain.xy and some-domain.co.xy are valid). I don't think you can make  (reasonably small) generic solution. Just put the constant in some configuration file and print it where needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the extremely low likelihood that our domain would ever change from anything other than .com, let alone to a SLD, I coded something like this in.

```
var temp = location.host.split('.').reverse();
var root_domain = '.' + temp[1] + '.' + temp[0];
```

The overhead and maintenance of maintaining a TLD or SLD list and comparing against it is not worth the trade off for us.

Comment: [tldjs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tldjs) can be used if you want to avoid the maintenance yourself. It is based on Mozilla public suffix list

Comment: You may want to use `location.hostname` rather than `host` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725890/location-host-vs-location-hostname-and-cross-browser-compatibility

Answer (score 16):

if you want it all on one line -

```
document.domain.split('.').reverse().splice(0,2).reverse().join('.')
```

or

```
location.hostname.split('.').reverse().splice(0,2).reverse().join('.')
```

for inputs: `'foo.example.com', 'foo.bar.example.com', 'foo.bar.fizz.buzz.example.com'`

it will return: `'example.com'`

Comment: Doesn’t work for .co.uk domains.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot call .co.uk as TLD. It is actually a [second level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain). So it'll always be ambiguous that what is the root domain.
However you can list all the available TLD's and Second Level Domains to and try to find a match. But that will be a very costly and tedious operation.
If you want to do this, this [List of TLDs and SLDs](https://github.com/gavingmiller/second-level-domains) might be useful:

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this:

```
const rootDomain = s => {
    const r =  /.*\.([^.]*[^0-9][^.]*\.[^.]*[^.0-9][^.]*$)/;
    return s.replace(r, '$1');
};
```

Which is similar in output to the above method using split, reverse etc., but it doesn't modify straight IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rootDomain = '.' + window.location.hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: @BDL This code is pretty standard and self-explaining. What more do you expect?

Comment: I suggest trimming this down to `const rootDomain =  location.hostname.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');`