# Get domain name from URL without java.net in Java

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to know in GWT is there an easy way to get host name from url WITHOUT java.net.*; Since client side doesn't support this package.

```
Input ejw.example.com/anotherexample?fun=no
output example.com

Input https://www3.example.com/yeteagainanotherexample?fun=miserable
output example.com
```

Comment: `ejw.example.com`, `www3.example.com` and `example.com` are all different domain names.

Comment: I meant host. And I am looking for a built-in method if it exist.

Comment: They are different host names as well :), because they can - and often do - resolve to different IP addresses. What you look for in your examples is a second-level domain name, but you have to make sure that this is really what you need.

Comment: Correct. 2nd level domain name. I would write my own method but if there was a built-in class that replaces java.net that would be great.

Comment: You may find an answer to this question very helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452916/need-a-regular-expression-to-capture-second-level-domain-sld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try with [com.google.gwt.regexp.shared.RegExp](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html) that is used for regular expressions with features like Javascript's RegExp, plus Javascript String's replace and split methods (which can take a RegExp parameter).

Try below regex that captures all the everything between first dot and first forward slash and get it at match index 1.

```
https*://\w+\.(.*?)/
```

Here is demo on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yTl3CPzbMSewN3SF) and [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/391gl)

Sample code:

```
String url="https://www3.example.com/yeteagainanotherexample?fun=miserable";

System.out.println(RegExp.compile("https*://\\w+\\.(.*?)/").exec(url).getGroup(1));
```

---

**Note:** I am not good in regex so please change the regex pattern as per your need. Read more about

- [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)
- [JavaScript Regex to match a URL in a field of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188645/javascript-regex-to-match-a-url-in-a-field-of-text)

Comment: Why do you think he needs his own domain name? I think the OP is talking about URLs in general.

Comment: And you did not provide the second-level domain name that the OP is looking for.

Comment: What about `blog.inside.example.co.uk`? Your regex fails. There can be up to 127 dots in domain name.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Sorry I have very little knowledge about URL domain name. It's just a example. The regex can be modified or simply use String#split() method.

Comment: String.splt() is also not trivial, because you need to distinguish between `blog.example.com` and `blog.example.com.me" - just to make up an example.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Sorry I don't know all the combination of the URL pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getHost()
```